# Drawing a polygon from UTM coordinates without using a computer

Tags: polygon, coordinates, gps, mapping, utm

all.

I'm having trouble remembering how I used to do something, and I can't find any answers so far online. Years ago, I would take various points of, say, a field using a handheld GPS. I would then plot these points on grid paper to create a sketch map of the field.

I'm struggling to articulate exactly what I mean, but I've basically forgotten the process of doing it without the aid of any computer software. I remember I would find the highest and lowest northing and easting, and this would give me the range to work in. I can't remember what figures I'm dropping off to accurately label the grid squares, either. I thought it was something like dropping off the last two, but I saw a video where the man dropped off the first two, and the last one, to give himself 4-figure grid squares.

Can anyone remember the step-by-step way of doing this? Apologies if I'm not making sense.

Comment: So you want to draw on a sheet of paper with a pen, did I understand that correctly? And you have only a set off coordinate values? You have the extent of the field (maximum and minimum lat/long coordinates) so you can label the x- and y- axes, right? OK, now: where are you stuck? What exactly is your question? Plese describe until which step you arrived and where the **first** problem appears - then someone can provide an answer for this and you can proceed and ask another question, if it is the case. That is how this site works. Please also post a screenshot of what you have.